# D3 Visualization of network data (nodes and links) via json file

Tags: javascript, python, json, d3.js, data-visualization

I would like to visualize network data that consists nodes and links in json file. I'm looking how D3 could be utilized. I haven't tried D3 but seems its good to visualize network data.

Lot of example visualization of data using D3 but I observed the link in json file example always based on source and target or nodes based on index....

If my json file doesn't have source and target key but instead the key used source and destination or the json nodes and links only content the values...can I still leverage D3..?

I expect I can edit D3 to follow my data or the other way a round?..I'm not sure on how to fit my json data onto D3 structure. I have gone the the D3 documentation and some examples but bit lost where to go... Appreciate someone could advise me further. Thank you

Please find example of data json i have

SAMPLE1 (only values of nodes and links):

```
{"nodes":["ser1","ser2","ser3","ser4","ser5"],"links":[["ser1","ser3",10], 
["ser1","ser5",30],["ser2","ser3",11],["ser3","ser4",10], 
["ser3","ser5",20],["ser2","ser5",30]]}


{
  "nodes": [
    "ser1",
    "ser2",
    "ser3",
    "ser4",
    "ser5"
  ],
  "links": [
    [
      "ser1",
      "ser3",
      10
    ],
    [
      "ser1",
      "ser5",
      30
    ],
    [
      "ser2",
      "ser3",
      11
    ],
    [
      "ser3",
      "ser4",
      10
    ],
    [
      "ser3",
      "ser5",
      20
    ],
    [
      "ser2",
      "ser5",
      30
    ]
  ]
}
```

SAMPLE2 (keys and values of nodes and links:

```
{"nodes":[{"name":"ser1"},{"name":"ser2"},{"name":"ser3"},{"name":"ser4"}, 
{"name":"ser5"}],"links":[{"source":"ser1","dest":"ser3","value":"10"}, 
{"source":"ser1","dest":"ser5","value":"10"}, 
{"source":"ser2","dest":"ser4","value":"30"}, 
{"source":"ser3","dest":"ser4","value":"10"}, 
{"source":"ser3","dest":"ser5","value":"10"}]}

    {
  "nodes": [
    {
      "name": "ser1"
    },
    {
      "name": "ser2"
    },
    {
      "name": "ser3"
    },
    {
      "name": "ser4"
    },
    {
      "name": "ser5"
    }
  ],
  "links": [
    {
      "source": "ser1",
      "dest": "ser3",
      "value": "10"
    },
    {
      "source": "ser1",
      "dest": "ser5",
      "value": "10"
    },
    {
      "source": "ser2",
      "dest": "ser4",
      "value": "30"
    },
    {
      "source": "ser3",
      "dest": "ser4",
      "value": "10"
    },
    {
      "source": "ser3",
      "dest": "ser5",
      "value": "10"
    }
  ]
}
```

my index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

.links line {
  stroke: #999;
  stroke-opacity: 0.6;
}

.nodes circle {
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

text {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 10px;
}

</style>
<svg width="960" height="600"></svg>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.9.1/d3.min.js"></script>
<script>

var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    width = +svg.attr("width"),
    height = +svg.attr("height");

var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory20);

var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
    .force("link", d3.forceLink().id(function(d) { return d.name; }))
    .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody())
    .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2));

  var graph = getData();
  graph.links = graph.links.map(function(ele) {return {
    source: ele.source, target: ele.dest, value: +ele.value
  }
 });

  var link = svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "links")
    .selectAll("line")
    .data(graph.links)
    .enter().append("line")
      .attr("stroke-width", function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.value); });

  var node = svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "nodes")
    .selectAll("g")
    .data(graph.nodes)
    .enter().append("g")

  var circles = node.append("circle")
      .attr("r", 5)
      .attr("fill", function(d) { return color(d.name); })
      .call(d3.drag()
          .on("start", dragstarted)
          .on("drag", dragged)
          .on("end", dragended));

  var lables = node.append("text")
      .text(function(d) {
        return d.name;
      })
      .attr('x', 6)
      .attr('y', 3);

  node.append("title")
      .text(function(d) { return d.name; });

  simulation
      .nodes(graph.nodes)
      .on("tick", ticked);

  simulation.force("link")
      .links(graph.links);

  function ticked() {
    link
        .attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
        .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
        .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
        .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

    node
        .attr("transform", function(d) {
          return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
        })
  }

function dragstarted(d) {
  if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
  d.fx = d.x;
  d.fy = d.y;
}

function dragged(d) {
  d.fx = d3.event.x;
  d.fy = d3.event.y;
}

function dragended(d) {
  if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0);
  d.fx = null;
  d.fy = null;
}

  function getData() {
    let json = {"nodes":[{"name":"ser1"},{"name":"ser2"},{"name":"ser3"},{"name":"ser4"},
    {"name":"ser5"}],"links":[{"source":"ser1","dest":"ser3","value":"10"},
    {"source":"ser1","dest":"ser5","value":"10"},
    {"source":"ser2","dest":"ser4","value":"30"},
    {"source":"ser3","dest":"ser4","value":"10"},
    {"source":"ser3","dest":"ser5","value":"10"}]};

    return json;
  }
</script>
```

my finding below 
(1) Only sample2 structure (json data) suitable and can fit onto D3 (Force Directed Graph) (2) To use D3 template, change (i) id=node key (ii) add graph.link = graph.links.map(function(ele) { return { source: ele.source, target: ele.dest, value: +ele.value } }); ( (3) Json data can be internal or external source (4) D3 can provide more values/info based on the data we have

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If you want to refer to a property of nodes as opposed to the index
>   (which is the default) you can use the function link.id().
>
> For reference, see: https://github.com/d3/d3-force#link_id

In your case, you can use sample2 and connect the links with the nodes in following way:

```
d3.forceSimulation()
.force("link", d3.forceLink().id(function(d) { return d.name; }))
```

and you just have to rename "dest" into "target":

```
graph.links = graph.links.map(function(ele) {
  return {
    source: ele.source, target: ele.dest, value: +ele.value
  }
});
```

I slightly adjusted an existing block to load your data, [see this example block](https://bl.ocks.org/ee2dev/fba676f35926b2705173564e13bf87cb).
In addition, I added a code snippet here:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    width = +svg.attr("width"),
    height = +svg.attr("height");

var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory20);

var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
    .force("link", d3.forceLink().id(function(d) { return d.name; }))
    .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody())
    .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2));

  var graph = getData();
  graph.links = graph.links.map(function(ele) {return {
    source: ele.source, target: ele.dest, value: +ele.value
  }
 });

  var link = svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "links")
    .selectAll("line")
    .data(graph.links)
    .enter().append("line")
      .attr("stroke-width", function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.value); });

  var node = svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "nodes")
    .selectAll("g")
    .data(graph.nodes)
    .enter().append("g")
    
  var circles = node.append("circle")
      .attr("r", 5)
      .attr("fill", function(d) { return color(d.name); })
      .call(d3.drag()
          .on("start", dragstarted)
          .on("drag", dragged)
          .on("end", dragended));

  var lables = node.append("text")
      .text(function(d) {
        return d.name;
      })
      .attr('x', 6)
      .attr('y', 3);

  node.append("title")
      .text(function(d) { return d.name; });

  simulation
      .nodes(graph.nodes)
      .on("tick", ticked);

  simulation.force("link")
      .links(graph.links);

  function ticked() {
    link
        .attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
        .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
        .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
        .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

    node
        .attr("transform", function(d) {
          return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
        })
  }

function dragstarted(d) {
  if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
  d.fx = d.x;
  d.fy = d.y;
}

function dragged(d) {
  d.fx = d3.event.x;
  d.fy = d3.event.y;
}

function dragended(d) {
  if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0);
  d.fx = null;
  d.fy = null;
}
  
  function getData() {
    let json = {"nodes":[{"name":"ser1"},{"name":"ser2"},{"name":"ser3"},{"name":"ser4"}, 
    {"name":"ser5"}],"links":[{"source":"ser1","dest":"ser3","value":"10"}, 
    {"source":"ser1","dest":"ser5","value":"10"}, 
    {"source":"ser2","dest":"ser4","value":"30"}, 
    {"source":"ser3","dest":"ser4","value":"10"}, 
    {"source":"ser3","dest":"ser5","value":"10"}]};

    return json;
  }
```

```css
.links line {
  stroke: #999;
  stroke-opacity: 0.6;
}

.nodes circle {
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

text {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.9.1/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg width="300" height="300"></svg>
```

Comment: My json links above is using source, dest and value as the key, how to map it with the source and target as stated in the index.html? Do i need to change source/target according to my links key? This part I'm still puzzle to understand it...appreciate some snippet that can apply based on my simple2 json...thank you

Comment: I added an example with your sample2 data

Comment: I follow ur sample above but nothing appeared on the browser...I provide my index.html above...

Comment: That’s strange - when you the run the code snippet button in my answer it should show the graph. Does it give an error message ?

Comment: Is it because I'm doing all in html file?

Comment: Ur code works good... i can run it and populate the node...just when I copy and paste to my file...it doesnt work

Comment: Your html file is wrong, at least you have to add the <body> and at the end the <\body> tag. Does my code snippet work if you run in stackoverflow ?

Comment: When i run ur code snippet in stackoverflow...ok..no problem... the index.html i follow from the example block and adjust it with ur code....

Comment: If you put the stylesin the <head> and the rest in the <body> if should work. I think you can omit the closing <\html>

Comment: Ok I see. I will double check tomorrow. The console should tell what the problem is...

Comment: In the code already hardcoded the json data....if i want call external json data ... how can i call json data as per sample code ---->d3.json("miserables.json", function(error, graph) {
  if (error) throw error;

Comment: Now it should be fine - I updated my answer and included a link to a block (https://bl.ocks.org/ee2dev/fba676f35926b2705173564e13bf87cb) with your data. I hope that works now - sorry for the confusion - I picked a block which was not compatible with all major browsers.

Comment: Hi sir thank you... it works..good.....i have asked u before..on how to use external json data instead of hardcoded.... d3.json("miserables.json", function(error, graph) { if (error) throw error;

Comment: the bl.ock contains json data from an external file.

Comment: Yup..u r amazing!..i just check the block...thank you sir.... pls find my finding below (1) Only sample2 structure (json data) suitable and can fit onto D3 (Force Directed Graph) (2) To use D3 template, change (i) id=node key (ii) add graph.link = graph.links.map(function(ele) {
      return {
        source: ele.source, target: ele.dest, value: +ele.value
      }
    }); ( (3) Json data can be internal or external source (4) D3 can provide more values/info based on the data we have . I think this is some of important tips to remember shall D3 to be deployed...

Comment: If you think your summary is helpful for anyone reading on stackoverflow, then please post your insights as an answer not a comment. Also, if my answered solved your question you can mark the answer as accepted (by clicking on the check mark to the left of my answer.